# CSS disappears every time a make an edit to the file

Tags: css

i'm trying to edit a css file that belongs to a website that is run by silex framework. 
So every time i edit the css file and save, it seems to disappear. i have made some research about it and can't get it sorted. any tips?

Comment: what you mean by "disappears" doesn't render at all on the DOM ? maybe you write wrong the CSS and all after your lines is ignored ?

Comment: @DaniP no i mean it disappears from the css file. like if i type in the end of the file a command such as " *{color: red;} " then save it- refresh the browser, neither does it render on the DOM nor can i find it back in the css file

Comment: Clean cache on your browser ---